# CentOS 6 in VMWare fusion: Unexpected MAC address change

Tags: centos, vmware, mac-address

I installed CentOS 6.X with VMWare Fusion.

It looks like the mac address and nic names changes randomly.

[image]

`eth8` and `eth9`, totally weird.

Anyone know why?

P.S VMWare pops a dialog asks me if I moved or copied the VM, although I never did anything to the Virtual Machine. And each time I choose `I moved it`, maybe it's relevant to the problem?

P.P.S I also have other Linux VMs, e.g Ubuntu which never had such problems, Hmm.

Comment: vmware assigns the MAC address(es) to the VMs.  check your vmware config.

Comment: @cas so how can I prevent this from changing?

Comment: i have no idea.  it's a vmware problem, not a unix or linux problem.  check your vmware config.  see also https://www.google.com/search?q=vmware+mac+address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [vmware-support](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_advanced_mac_address.html) You need to assign the MAC adress manually to avoid changes in the MAC automatically evrytime you moved it.

> If you want to guarantee that the same MAC address is assigned to a given virtual machine every time, even if the virtual machine is moved, or if you want to guarantee a unique MAC address for each virtual machine within a networked environment, you can assign the address manually instead of allowing VMware Workstation to assign it automatically.
>
> To assign the same, unique MAC address to any virtual machine manually, use a text editor to remove three lines from the configuration file and add one line. The configuration file has a.vmx extension at the end of the filename. On a Linux host, a virtual machine created with an earlier VMware product may have a configuration file with a .cfg extension.

As it's described:

Remove the three lines that begin with the following from the configuration file:

```
 ethernet[n].generatedAddress
 ethernet[n].addressType
 ethernet[n].generatedAddressOffset
```

In these options, [n] is the number of the virtual Ethernet adapter — for example ethernet0.

Add the following line to the configuration file:

```
ethernet[n].address = 00:50:56:XX:YY:ZZ
```

Or you can edit the file like the following example:

```
ethernet[n].addressType = "static"
ethernet[n].checkMACAddress = "false"
ethernet[n].address = "00:50:56:XX:YY:ZZ"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Do you also know how to reset nic names like eth10 to eth0?

Comment: Save the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth10` and create a new one for `eth0` , Open `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` chage `eth10` by `eth0`